# One-line initialize a C++ object in map

Tags: c++, clang, c++17

What is the proper way to initialize a class and assign to the unordered_map directly?

```
#include <string>

#include <unordered_map>
int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, Foo> s;
  // Foo foo{1};
  s["test"] = Foo(1); // this is bad
  return 0;
}
```

*Foo.h*

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int x)
      : x_(x) {}

  private:
    int x_;
};
```

Now I get

```
main.cpp:19:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo, std::hash<std::__cxx11::string>, std::equal_to<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Foo> > >::operator[]' requested here
  s["test"] = Foo(1);
   ^
Foo.h:3:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'x', but no arguments were provided
    Foo(int x)
    ^
Foo.h:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class Foo {
      ^
Foo.h:1:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
```

The problem is to do with `s["test"] = Foo(1)`.

Comment: "`// this is bad`" - I'll bet that when you profile (an optimized build of) your application and look for bottlenecks, this won't even show up on the top-100 list. Don't worry about it.

Comment: If you want to say `s["test"] = Foo(1);` then you need a default constructor for `Foo` or is your question about alternatives to `s["test"] = Foo(1);`?

Answer (score 6):

Elements in a map must be default constructible when you want to use `operator[]`, because it default constructs the value for the given key when it does not yet exist in the map. Either make your `Foo` default constructible or use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) or [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) instead.

Default constructible `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int x = 0)   // <- can be called without parameters
      : x_(x) {}

  private:
    int x_;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`s["test"] = Foo(1)` will default-initialize the object at `s["test"]` and then copy (or move) assign to it from the temporary `Foo` object created by `Foo(1)`.

This falls apart because `Foo` doesn't have a default constructor, so it can't be default-initialized.

You can use one of `unordered_map`'s [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert), [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace), or [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) methods to get around this.  For example:

```
s.try_emplace("test", 1)
```

This will directly construct a new `Foo` object in `s` with the key `"test"` and pass `1` to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have a default constructor, you need to use [`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), or [`std::map::try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace).

E.g.

```
s.emplace(std::make_pair("test", Foo(1)));
```

or the simpler form

```
s.emplace("test", Foo(1));
```